# Error system: while using correct path: Bad file descriptor (BOOST::FileSystem)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

[Current files and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDuZI.png)

```
std::string file="strat"+std::to_string(choice);
plugin = dll::import<plugin_api>(          // type of imported symbol is located between `<` and `>`
        lib_path/file,                     // path to the library and library name
        "plugin",                                       // name of the symbol to import
        dll::load_mode::append_decorations              // makes `libmy_plugin_sum.so` or `my_plugin_sum.dll` from `my_plugin_sum`
);
```

I have the above code and get the error : `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
  what():  boost::dll::shared_library::load() failed (dlerror system message: /home/deepansh/Desktop/Plugin_example/plugins/strat1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory): Bad file descriptor
Aborted (core dumped)`

I am new to boost and c++, can someone help me here? I am following https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.factory_method_in_plugin

Comment: what is  `lib_path/file` ? can you get a valid parameter from dividing `lib_path` by `file` ?

Comment: Here's the obvious questions. Firstly do you have a file called `/home/deepansh/Desktop/Plugin_example/plugins/strat1` on your system? The error message is telling you that you don't. Secondly is that the correct file name? I looks like you are trying to load a shared library, in which case I would expect to see the extension `.so` in your filename, but I could be wrong.

Comment: yeah there file called strat1.cpp at the location. I am following https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.factory_method_in_plugin and lib_pah is oost::dll::fs::path lib_path("/home/deepansh/Desktop/Plugin_example/plugins");

Comment: @idclev463035818: Yes, `operator/` is overloaded with the obvious meaning.

Comment: that is not division to be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There's a file called `strat1.cpp`". That's not the file you are trying to load, and a .cpp file isn't compiled yet. You'll need to make an `strat1.so` file, and load that.

Comment: I am using dynamic loading, the so file is built at runtime only, Ia am following tutorial 1 of : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.factory_method_in_plugin                                                                                                                                      please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @DeepanshNagaria: _How_ is the .so file built at runtime? AFAICT, Boost won't build the file for you. I mean, Boost can't guess what compiler and linker commands are needed for that.

Comment: I tried compiling those files too using **gcc -c -fPIC strat1.cpp** to get the .so files and even the .o files but still i get the same error

Comment: Well, the file you currently are trying to load is called  `/home/deepansh/Desktop/Plugin_example/plugins/strat1`, so you might want to add `".so"` to `std::string file`.